# How to get text from website to string?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

How to get XML from [this URL](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/JsD6uEZsIsU/related) into `String` on Android? I was trying to do it with tutorials, but no way was successful. Here is my code:

```
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String text = "";
    try {
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url); 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String line = "";
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            text += line; 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: So what happens with your code?

Comment: is it returning an empty string or just crashes? if second please post your logcat

Comment: I'm sorry it works now. I dont know where was problem. But although is better way to get that string?

Comment: https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&docid=XnpVp86B6mYuOM&tbnid=0ygZg3_RIf6VhM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.masti-xpress.com%2F120926%2FStory-of-Every-Programmer.php&ei=lEdCUfaqAYWitAbL3IDABQ&bvm=bv.43828540,d.Yms&psig=AFQjCNG34DJSVY-lfIC8UqFl6CEpSzR7dg&ust=1363384593887923